# Trace connection to Through hole via

Tags: pcb

I am designing a 2 layer PCB. I have a question about trace connection to through hole.
Which of these is correct way of connecting a trace to through hole via?
a)[image: Connection type 1]

b) [image: Connection type 2]

Thanks!

Comment: As long as you don't violate clearance tolerances, either will work. But b is the norm.

Comment: The via should have solid copper pads (not the copper ring you show) on both layers, and the trace should run to the center of the pad. (The center of the pad will, of course, be drilled out eventually, but the PCB artwork should show a solid disc for the pad. (unless you're doing something really strange))

Comment: HI Peter, I am using Ultiboard and I didn't change any settings for vias. The via properties say that the pad is 31 mils and drill dia is 16 mils. I am not sure how to show the through hole vias with copper pad.

Comment: Both are fine. Just try to avoid copper intersecions with acute angles. I am not familiar with Ultiboard, but I think most layout software shows the via holes. I would not worry about it. You can check the gerbers with a gerber viewer before sending the files to fab, to make sure the pads are solid.

Comment: It is OK to come in off center on the square pad, because doing so produces no acute angles. It would not be OK to come in off-center on the round pad, because then you would get an acute angle on one side. However, the trace can turn when it gets just a very short distance from the via pad.

Comment: The X you've drawn in the middle of the square pad is completely redundant.

Comment: Oh, yeah, the X is going to be copper anyway because of the square pad.

Answer (score 1):

Variant "b" is correct. But "a" will also be correct, after moving wire to corner of square pad on 45 degree or align it to center of the pad's edge.

Also, design rules for PCB described in standards IEC 61188-x-x.

Answer (score -2):

none are correct! pad center should be left CLEAR to act as center punch or guide for drill resulting in precise drilling for through hole boards, works perfect every time. trace to center causes drill to step to one side resulting in crooked hole lines for ic's etc, the pad footprint is required to supply enough copper for the component 'NOT THE TRACE??????????????'.